# How to debug Apollo Graphql

Tags: debugging, graphql, apollo

I am getting this error "Variable $id of required type "String!" was not provided"

This is quite a large project and I am using the variable name id at many places. How do I debug apollo graphql in a way that will tell me which query is causing the error?

This is how my apollo client is set up with regards to error debugging:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach((v) => {
      console.log(
        util.inspect(v, { showHidden: false, depth: 3, colorize: true })
    );
  });
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  connectToDevTools: isBrowser,
  ssrMode: !isBrowser,
  link: from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache
});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
{ message: 'Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.',
  locations: [ { line: 1, column: 37 } ],
  extensions: 
   { code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
     exception: 
      { stacktrace: 
         [ 'GraphQLError: Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.',
           '    at _loop (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:92:17)',
           '    at coerceVariableValues (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:119:16)',
           '    at getVariableValues (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:48:19)',
           '    at buildExecutionContext (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:184:61)',
           '    at executeImpl (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:89:20)',
           '    at Object.execute (/app/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:64:35)',
           '    at /app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:261:48',
           '    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)',
           '    at /app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:8:71',
           '    at new Promise (<anonymous>)',
           '    at __awaiter (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:12)',
           '    at execute (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:240:20)',
           '    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:177:42)',
           '    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)',
           '    at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:5:58)',
           '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)' ] } } }
```

As you can see the error doesn't really give me much to work with, since the variable name is used often. And my project is really large at this point, so trial and error will take forever. Does anybody have any ideas on what I can try?

I am trying to use the apollo browser dev tool, but I am not really getting any interesting data from that one either.